# Convert CSV to specific format using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, csv, anychart

I'm working off of this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.14.0/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.14.0/anychart-ui.min.css" />
  <style>
    html, body, #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
  // create data set on our data
  var dataSet = anychart.data.set(getData());

  // map data for the first series, take x from the zero column and value from the first column of data set
  var seriesData_1 = dataSet.mapAs({
    x: [0],
    value: [1]
  });

  // map data for the second series, take x from the zero column and value from the second column of data set
  var seriesData_2 = dataSet.mapAs({
    x: [0],
    value: [2]
  });

  // map data for the third series, take x from the zero column and value from the third column of data set
  var seriesData_3 = dataSet.mapAs({
    x: [0],
    value: [3]
  });

  // create line chart
  chart = anychart.line();

  // turn on chart animation
  chart.animation(true);

  // set chart padding
  chart.padding([10, 20, 5, 20]);

  // turn on the crosshair
  chart.crosshair()
    .enabled(true)
    .yLabel(false)
    .yStroke(null);

  // set tooltip mode to point
  chart.tooltip().positionMode('point');

  // set chart title text settings
  chart.title('Trend of Sales of the Most Popular Products of ACME Corp.');
  chart.title().padding([0, 0, 5, 0]);

  // set yAxis title
  chart.yAxis().title('Number of Bottles Sold (thousands)');
  chart.xAxis().labels().padding([5]);

  // create first series with mapped data
  var series_1 = chart.line(seriesData_1);
  series_1.name('Brandy');
  series_1.hoverMarkers()
    .enabled(true)
    .type('circle')
    .size(4);
  series_1.tooltip()
    .position('right')
    .anchor('left')
    .offsetX(5)
    .offsetY(5);

  // create second series with mapped data
  var series_2 = chart.line(seriesData_2);
  series_2.name('Whiskey');
  series_2.hoverMarkers()
    .enabled(true)
    .type('circle')
    .size(4);
  series_2.tooltip()
    .position('right')
    .anchor('left')
    .offsetX(5)
    .offsetY(5);

  // create third series with mapped data
  var series_3 = chart.line(seriesData_3);
  series_3.name('Tequila');
  series_3.hoverMarkers()
    .enabled(true)
    .type('circle')
    .size(4);
  series_3.tooltip()
    .position('right')
    .anchor('left')
    .offsetX(5)
    .offsetY(5);

  // turn the legend on
  chart.legend()
    .enabled(true)
    .fontSize(13)
    .padding([0, 0, 10, 0]);

  // set container id for the chart and set up paddings
  chart.container('container');

  // initiate chart drawing
  chart.draw();
});

function getData() {
  return [
    ['1986', 3.6, 2.3, 2.8, 11.5],
    ['1987', 7.1, 4.0, 4.1, 14.1],
    ['1988', 8.5, 6.2, 5.1, 17.5],
    ['1989', 9.2, 11.8, 6.5, 18.9],
    ['1990', 10.1, 13.0, 12.5, 20.8],
    ['1991', 11.6, 13.9, 18.0, 22.9],
    ['1992', 16.4, 18.0, 21.0, 25.2],
    ['1993', 18.0, 23.3, 20.3, 27.0],
    ['1994', 13.2, 24.7, 19.2, 26.5],
    ['1995', 12.0, 18.0, 14.4, 25.3],
    ['1996', 3.2, 15.1, 9.2, 23.4],
    ['1997', 4.1, 11.3, 5.9, 19.5],
    ['1998', 6.3, 14.2, 5.2, 17.8],
    ['1999', 9.4, 13.7, 4.7, 16.2],
    ['2000', 11.5, 9.9, 4.2, 15.4],
    ['2001', 13.5, 12.1, 1.2, 14.0],
    ['2002', 14.8, 13.5, 5.4, 12.5],
    ['2003', 16.6, 15.1, 6.3, 10.8],
    ['2004', 18.1, 17.9, 8.9, 8.9],
    ['2005', 17.0, 18.9, 10.1, 8.0],
    ['2006', 16.6, 20.3, 11.5, 6.2],
    ['2007', 14.1, 20.7, 12.2, 5.1],
    ['2008', 15.7, 21.6, 10, 3.7],
    ['2009', 12.0, 22.5, 8.9, 1.5]
  ]
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Imagine I wanted to use other data and it is not in the same format as getData(), rather it is in CSV form. Is there a functionality in Anychart that allows me to import CSV data or JSON formatted data, using this exact style?

If not, how do I write a script that automatically converts my CSV into this readable format?

My CSV looks something like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2004-08-19,49.96,51.98,47.93,50.12,
2004-08-20,50.69,54.49,50.2,54.1,
2004-08-23,55.32,56.68,54.47,54.65,
2004-08-24,55.56,55.74,51.73,52.38,
2004-08-25,52.43,53.95,51.89,52.95,
2004-08-26,52.42,53.92,52.28,53.9,
2004-08-27,54.0,54.26,52.79,53.02,
```

Comment: You have provided much too much unnecessary information/code, which makes people less inclined to try to answer your question. Please read [how to ask a minimal, complete and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and note in particular that a question should be "minimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSV data with AnyChart without formatting, there is an article about it in the documentation: https://docs.anychart.com/7.14.0/Working_with_Data/Data_From_CSV

Herer is a sample with the data in your CSV format:

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
  // create data set on our data
  var dataSet = anychart.data.set(getData(),{ignoreFirstRow: true});

  // map data for the first series, take x from the zero column and value from the first column of data set
  var seriesData_1 = dataSet.mapAs({
    x: [0],
    open: [1],
    high: [2],
    low: [3],
    close: [4],

  });

  // map data for the second series, take x from the zero column and value from the second column of data set
  var seriesData_2 = dataSet.mapAs({
    x: [0],
    value: [5]
  });


  // create line chart
  chart = anychart.line();

  // create first series with mapped data
  var series_1 = chart.ohlc(seriesData_1);


  volumeScale = anychart.scales.linear();
  chart.yAxis(1).scale(volumeScale);
  chart.yAxis(1).orientation("right");

  // create second series with mapped data
  var series_2 = chart.line(seriesData_2);
  series_2.yScale(volumeScale);

  // draw
  chart.container('container').draw();
});

function getData() {
  return 'Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\n' +
'2004-08-19,49.96,51.98,47.93,50.12,100\n' +
'2004-08-20,50.69,54.49,50.2,54.1,1200\n' +
'2004-08-23,55.32,56.68,54.47,54.65,110\n' +
'2004-08-24,55.56,55.74,51.73,52.38,111\n' +
'2004-08-25,52.43,53.95,51.89,52.95,105\n' +
'2004-08-26,52.42,53.92,52.28,53.9,100\n' +
'2004-08-27,54.0,54.26,52.79,53.02,90\n'
}
```

Linke to the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bdhzrac3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Anychart, so I don't know if there is any built-in functionality there to do what you want. However, a generic approach is shown below where the csv text is split into lines, the lines are split into "words", and the words are processed as necessary to either extract the year as a string or convert a string data value into a numerical data value.

The code below only converts the input data *in the exact format shown* into output data *in the exact format shown*. If the formats of either the input or output change, the processing would have to be changed appropriately. However, the code below at least shows one strategy for how to accomplish that.

The `newline` character is placed within a variable just in case you ever have to process csv data that has a character other than "\n" at the end of each line.

```js
const newline = '\n';

const csv =
`

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2004-08-19,49.96,51.98,47.93,50.12,
2004-08-20,50.69,54.49,50.2,54.1,
2004-08-23,55.32,56.68,54.47,54.65,
2004-08-24,55.56,55.74,51.73,52.38,
2004-08-25,52.43,53.95,51.89,52.95,
2004-08-26,52.42,53.92,52.28,53.9,
2004-08-27,54.0,54.26,52.79,53.02,


`;

/*
desired format:
    ['1986', 3.6, 2.3, 2.8, 11.5],
    ['1987', 7.1, 4.0, 4.1, 14.1],
    etc.
*/

const processCSV = csv =>
  csv
    .replace(RegExp(`^${newline}+`, 'g'), '') // eliminate extra newlines at the beginning
    .replace(RegExp(`${newline}+$`, 'g'), '') // eliminate extra newlines at the end
    .split(newline) // split the csv string into lines
    .slice(1) // eliminate the unnecessary first header line
    .map(line => { // process each line
      const elmts = line
        .replace(/,+$/g, '') // remove any trailing commas
        .split(','); // split the line into data elements
      const year = elmts[0].slice(0,4); // extract the year from the first element
      const data = elmts.slice(1).map(num => +num); // convert all remaining values to numbers
      return [year, ...data]; // return the data for each line
    });
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(processCSV(csv)));
```